# Add an ignored tag link is not required in the ignored tags edit mode

Tags: bug, design, ignored-tags

When editing the Favorite Tags, under the Ignored Tags section there is a link
**Add an ignored tag** is visible. Clicking on the link it didn't respond any.

After click anywhere in the screen, I can see the **Add an ignored tag** is still visible and clicking on that it is functioning correctly.

If you are see the Favorite Tags section, the **Add a favorite tag** is not visible in the edit mode, in the same way the **Add an ignored tag** link is also not required in the edit mode.

GIF for the same:

> [image: GIF for the question]